# Finding an inequality indicating an acute angle

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A = (1, 2, 1), B = (3, 4, −2)$ and $C = (x, y, z)$, find an inequality that is equivalent to the statement “$\angle ABC$ is acute.”

I am confused as to where to begin and what exactly the question Is asking. I am assuming it is a vector based problem?

Comment: Vectors ease the problem.

Answer (score 1):

hint :The angle $ABC$ is acute if and only if , equivalently if  $\vec{BA}.\vec{BC} >0$.

Comment: I think that $\angle ABC$ is the **angle** whose vertex is $B$ and whose sides are $BA$ and $BC$.

Comment: Ah... I misinterpreted the wording! Thanks! I will edit!

Answer (score 0):

By the [(converse) Pythagorean theorem](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt668/emat6680.folders/brooks/6690stuff/righttriangle/pythagconv.html), a triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$ is acute-angled iff $a^2<b^2+c^2$, $b^2<a^2+c^2$ and $c^2<a^2+b^2$. You may use the (direct) Pythagorean theorem to find $a^2,b^2$ and $c^2$ in terms of $x,y,z$ only.

Equivalently, your triangle is acute-angled iff the $C$ vertex lies outside the sphere having $AB$ as a diameter (that has a known centre and a known radius) and the projection of $C$ on $AB$ lies between $A$ and $B$. It follows that the locus of $C$ points for which $ABC$ is an acute-angled triangle is given by the region between two parallel planes, minus a solid sphere.

If we are just interested in $\widehat{ABC}$ being acute, we just need to require that $b^2<a^2+c^2$, i.e. that $C$ lies in the correct half-space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the triangle to be acute. (All 3 angles)

The angle is obtuse if $x,y,z$ lies inside the sphere with AB as its diameter.

It is also obtuse if it lies outside the planes perpendicular to AB with A and B as endpoints.

to make the triangle acute, then, $x,y,z$ must be outside the sphere, and inside the two planes.

$(x-1.5)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-1)^2 > 7.25$
and

$3< 2x + 2y - 3z < 20$

If you just care about one angle, then there are 3 inequalities in play, and you which is the right one.

$\angle ABC$ is the plane with $B$ as the endpoint.

$2x + 2y - 3z < 20$